# .substring() throws a nullPointerException

Tags: java

I am creating a Chess program on NetBeans using jButtons as squares, and my java knowledge is limited to what I have learnt at school.

So this line

```
int verticalValue = Integer.parseInt(newButton.substring(1,1));
```

returns a nullPointerException and I can't figure it out whatsoever. Here is the relevant code:

```
static void pawnMovement(JButton but){
    String buttonName = but.getName();
    String newButton = buttonName;
    int verticalValue = Integer.parseInt(newButton.substring(1,1));
```

The names of all buttons are in the format letterNumber, so I don't see why this shouldn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: simply print the value of `newButton` and see it yourself though substring is innocent in this case

Comment: Seems to be a classical NullPointerException... What does `but.getName();` return? Certainly, it returns *null* and thats your problem... Chech this before using the variable `newButton` or `buttonName`

Answer (score 2):

This code should produce a NumberFormatException as the string from `substring(1, 1)` will always be empty, unless newButton is `null` because it hasn't been set.

I would check in your debugger that is has been set. I would also ensure you are trying to parse at least 1 character.

Comment: It's really amazing to see that your answer appears more valuable to people even though you _technically didn't_ answer the question. Reputation, indeed, has a huge role to play, I guess. No offence.

Comment: @PankajSinghal maybe you know something I don't but often new developers don't read the error message and don't realise they are not all the same. I made the point that if the OP believes the value can't be null perhaps they misread the exception.

Comment: Totally agree with you, and it is the reality what you have said. But I was making a different point. :)

Comment: @PankajSinghal my impression is that upvoting had an element of randomness.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe. But, I seriously didn't need a sympathetic upvote (if you did it).

Comment: @PankajSinghal I upvoted because you might be correct (there is not enough information in the question IMHO)

Comment: Yeah, I sure did a dangerous thing, in the computing world, of making an _assumption_

Answer (score 1):

When you do a `new JButton("name")` - it sets the variable `JButton.text` as `name`. Hence, `but.getText()` should work for you.

In your case, `but.getName()` returns `NULL` because you have NOT done `but.setName()` first. `but.setName()` is required for `but.getName()` to work.

Hence, `buttonName` & `newButton` are `NULL`.

Hence, when you do `newButton.substring(1,1)` - it causes NPE because `newButton` is `NULL`